# Angular 4 : Call AppComponent Method from Another Component

Tags: angular

I have a logout bouton in shared page, but i want to call logout method  after clicked.
the implementation of my logout function is in app.comoponent.ts

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of Shared service here. Have your method implemented in a shared service and call the method from your login and shared component.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple solutions to this question.

1.) You have to follow this steps:

1. Create a service.
2. Create a BuheviorSubject(or ReplaySubject) RXJS in service.
3. In component B on event use next method in Subject (from service).
4. Subscribe in App component (on Subject from service) to it and do what you want.

2.) You have to follow this steps and Correct one:

1. Create a service.
2. Do all http request and so on in service.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, I juste move my login bouton to a new header component and i move my implimentation to the header.comoponent.ts